# setting up dual boot for Lenovo ideapad500 with Windows10 and ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, windows, lenovo, windows-10

Is it possible/safe to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad 500 with preinstalled Win10 OS, now without any issues for a dual boot? I have read that there were problems with the drivers earlier, have they been resolved? Absolute beginner with linux here and thanks in advance.

Comment: Drivers problems have nothing to do - directly - with whether or not it is safe to dual boot. It always is provided you know what you're doing and the hardware is in good working condition. If there are missing or non-working drivers that affects a single OS installation of Ubuntu as well as Ubuntu in dual boot.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is still dealing with driver bugs..go for 14.04 instead of 16.04

Comment: Thanks for your insights guys.CelticWarrior and minigeek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu. Ubuntu won't break your hardware. At worst, some hardware components may not work, such as Bluetooth or the touchpad. Even then hardware incompatibility is rare. Ubuntu works on most all computers from most all manufacturers. The Ideapad 500 is a fairly bog-standard laptop, and all components should work.

Actually, the biggest issue that might occur would be if you have a Intel Skylake-based Ideapad 500 (core i-6xxx). Skylake support under linux is currently very sketchy in terms of sleep state and power management support. This means that you will have far worse battery life, and in a worst case scenario your processor may be affected by the continuous current (and therefore, heat).

I managed to fix the sleep state issue on my Pavilion x360 by disabling my Ethernet port and upgrading to Kernel 4.7.2, but its a hit or miss with other manufacturers.

Haswell>= based PC's should be perfectly fine.

Warning: Be somewhat careful when installing Ubuntu, as you can very easily break your Windows partition if you overwrite it. However, the latest Ubuntu installer is quite user friendly and shouldn't be terribly hard to use.

--upvote if this helped! :)--

Comment: I do have the Skylake-based machine. I think I`m ok using a VM currently. However i cannot understand what I`d miss out on, compared to having Ubuntu on my machine directly vs having it on a VM. Thank you for sharing your experience

Comment: @PhoneSam VM's are far slower than dual boots unless you use a hardware passthrough. However, VM's are the safest way to use Linux. If you want to use Windows as your primary OS, then use a VM. If you want to use Linux to do more than dabble, then dual-boot. Another easy way to Linux is to use Wubi. Wubi is by default supported under Legacy systems. However, there are UEFI insallers that work fine.